# do I need to use insert delayed in this scenario?

Tags: php, mysql

I do have a Mysql database table which is always reading and inserting at a time. so do I need to use `INSERT DELAYED` option to optimize the process?? reading is primary concern and insert is secondary..

Comment: Are you using `MyISAM`, `MEMORY`, `ARCHIVE`, or `BLACKHOLE` tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if reading is the primary concern then you should use `INSERT DELAYED`.

> The DELAYED option for the INSERT statement is a MySQL extension to
>   standard SQL that is very useful if you have clients that cannot or
>   need not wait for the INSERT to complete.

This will also make `INSERT`s faster if there are a lot of separate `INSERT`s being made. This is because they are bundled together and written in one block.

[MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html)